# Convert timezone offset to hours & minutes preserving sign

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, timezone

Suppose I have an offset like this:

```
$secOffset =  -28800
```

I need it to convert in a format that is usable with MYSQL function `convert_tz()`

If I use `gmdate("h:i", secOffset)` I got `16:00` that is almost correct but It miss the minus `-` (that is quite important)

**Alternative approach:**

Suppose I have a time string `America/Los_Angeles` and I want to convert in a offset useful for MYSQL function `convert_tz()`

The final expected output is the offset from GMT so given a timezone.
For ex, having a timezone like `America/Los_Angeles`, the output should be:
`−08:00`

I'm on Magento/Zend so if any available function is on Zend I can accept answer based on it.

Comment: Explain your question what you want actually and what is your expected output?

Comment: ok done ... I think now is more clear

Comment: A timezone identifier doesn't necessarily correspond to a single offset. It depends on the time of year (DST).

Comment: I think it correspond to a precise offset for a precise date, I need to have an output that is dynamic for `today` ( or better the moment when the code is run )

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `DateTimeZone` and `DateInterval` classes for this:

```
$tzid = 'America/Los_Angeles';

$tz = new DateTimeZone($tzid);
$date = new DateTime('now', $tz);

// create a new date offset by the timezone offset
// gets the interval as hours & minutes
$offset = $tz->getOffset($date) . ' seconds';
$dateOffset = clone $date;
$dateOffset->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString($offset));

$interval = $dateOffset->diff($date);
$formatted = $interval->format('%R%H:%I');
```

This is a little convoluted, as you first get the timezone offset in seconds, and then use `DateTime` to help convert that interval into hours/mins.

Comment: looks working but also a bit over complicated  ... ( more java than php :) anyway thanks

Comment: If you want some crappy procedural code, try `($offset<0?'-':'+') . gmdate('h:i',abs($offset));` :-)

Comment: Thanks @cmbuckley nice code. But should not the hour format be `H:i` instead ? With `h:i`, an offset of 0 would result in `+12:00`...!

Comment: I did mention that was crappy code ;-) but yes, you're right, `H:i` is better there.